# OpenMPI array of blocking receives not working properly(In some cases program doesn't stop)

Tags: c, mpi, distributed-computing

I consider this to be an extremely weird issue:
I have this code:
it is supposed to receive a 2d matrix of size chunk and width.
Matrix is allocated using  :

```
int **alloc2d(int n, int m) {
    int i = 0;
    int *data = malloc(n * m * sizeof(int));
    int **array = malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        array[i] = &(data[i * m]);
    }
    return array;
}
```

So it is a continuos memory block.

I have the following code :

```
MPI_Status st;
int worker;
       for(i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        MPI_Recv(&(recmat[0][0]), chunk*width, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 1,
                                 MPI_COMM_WORLD, &st);

        worker = st.MPI_SOURCE;
      /*  for(k = worker * chunk; k < (worker + 1) * chunk; k++){
            for(j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                mat[k][j] = recmat[k - worker * chunk][j];
                }
            }*/
        }
```

If code is like this, everything stops and works well.
If I uncomment the  region:

```
for(k = worker * chunk; k < (worker + 1) * chunk; k++){
                for(j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                    mat[k][j] = recmat[k - worker * chunk][j];
                    }
                }
```

the thread running this code does not stop, I cannot find an logical explanation for this. Perhaps someone can see the error or the issue. Thank you!

recmat allocation and chunk calculation :

```
int **recmat;
recmat = alloc2d(chunk,width);
int chunk;
chunk = height / size;
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this, which makes me think that the issue is elsewhere.  Can you show us how chunk is calculated and how recmat and mat are allocated?

Comment: I realise it's difficult to see the issue without the whole code. What I am doing is: I have a master that sends data to several slaves, computes some data, then has this array of receives from workers. If workers finish their task and send data before the master gets to the receive, will the data be lost or stored in a buffer?

Comment: No; what you have is fine; the issue is almost certainly not there, it's in code that isn't posted, which makes answering the question difficult.

Comment: The above issue is part of a academic homework and I am reluctant to post it due to possible plagiarism. If I could send you an private message with the code paste, will it help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, this is too long to fit in a comment:

The code you've posted is fine; for instance, putting enough code around it to make it run produces the correct results (below).  So the issue is not where you think it is.

If you see code locking up in places you don't think it ought to, this frequently points to weird memory errors or something else going on.  You're best of just running it through a debugger, or through something like valgrind to check for memory problems.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int **alloc2d(int n, int m) {
    int i = 0;
    int *data = malloc(n * m * sizeof(int));
    int **array = malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        array[i] = &(data[i * m]);
    }
    return array;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int rank, size;
    const int height=10, width=10;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    int **recmat;
    int chunk;
    chunk = height / size;

    if (chunk*size != height) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: number of ranks %d does not divide size %d\n",
                     argv[0], size, height);
        MPI_Finalize();
        exit(1);
    }

    if (rank == 0) {
        int **recmat = alloc2d(chunk,width);
        int **mat = alloc2d(height,width);
        int worker;
        int i,j,k;
        MPI_Status st;

        /* deal with my own submatrix */
        for (k=0; k<chunk; k++) {
            for (j=0; j<width; j++) {
                mat[k][j] = 0;
            }
        }

        for(i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            MPI_Recv(&(recmat[0][0]), chunk*width, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 1,
                                     MPI_COMM_WORLD, &st);

            worker = st.MPI_SOURCE;
            for(k = worker * chunk; k < (worker + 1) * chunk; k++){
                for(j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                    mat[k][j] = recmat[k - worker * chunk][j];
                }
            }
        }

        free(&(recmat[0][0]));
        free(recmat);

        printf("Rank 0: mat is \n");
        for (int i=0; i<height; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<width; j++) {
                printf("%2d ", mat[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        free(&(mat[0][0]));
        free(mat);

    } else {
        int **sendmat = alloc2d(chunk,width);
        for (int i=0; i<chunk; i++)
            for (int j=0; j<width; j++)
                sendmat[i][j] = rank;

        MPI_Send(&(sendmat[0][0]), chunk*width, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        free(&(sendmat[0][0]));
        free(sendmat);
    }


    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There were so many errors and bugs in my code that it's not even worth mentioning, I'm sorry for this useless question ...

Answer (score 0):

This is also a longer comment. You can prevent double copy of the received data if you first probe for the message and then use the rank from the status to directly receive the content of the message into the big matrix:

```
for(i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    MPI_Probe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &st);
    worker = st.MPI_SOURCE;
    MPI_Recv(&(mat[worker*chunk][0]), chunk*width, MPI_INT,
             worker, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &st);
}
```

Less code and should work faster.